# C# proper locking

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, locking

Let's say I have such actions performed:

```
A.B.C.add(new D());
A.B.add(new C));
A.add(new B));
```

Those actions are performed **all at the same time**. Imagine that these are in three different methods.

```
lock(A.B.C)
   A.B.C.add(new D());

lock(A.B)
   A.B.add(new C));

lock(A)
   A.add(new B));
```

Are these locks independent? In other words - will these actions be performed at the same time, or each only after the previous one has been finished?

If it is correct - is it the most efficient way to set locks?

**EDIT**

I have lots of invokations of those kinds (these 3 methods are called many many times).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the locks are independent from each other. The `lock` statement actually creates a monitor on the argument instance, it does not take into account how you actually got there (i.e. the property chain `A.B.C`).

However, there is a subtle issue with your code. Since the locks are independent and the three lock statements may be executed at the same time, any statements like

```
lock(A.B.C)
    A.B.C.Add(new D());
```

are dangerous because when the lock is acquired, the property A.B.C might have changed. Thus, it would be better (i.e. safer) to use a local variable for this:

```
var c = A.B.C;
lock(c)
    c.Add(new D());
```

Comment: Sorry to revive an old post, I was looking for some best practice on locks. Regarding your last part, I think the best practice is not to lock on the object your are actually using but to lock an independent static object. Something like `public static object LockABC = new object();` and then to do `lock(LockABC) ...`

Comment: @samuelguedon Yes, it is usually better to use dedicated lock objects because you can be sure that you are the only one locking it. However, using a dedicated static lock object in this case completely changes the locking behavior. It is not possible to judge that without seeing the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Those statements will be performed at the same time. You can test this simply by running the below code and seeing that the console writes all occur immediately:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    lock (a.B.C)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a.B.C");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});

Task.Run(() =>
{
    lock (a.B)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a.B");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});

Task.Run(() =>
{
    lock (a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
});
```

From [C# reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx):

> Best practice is to define a private object to lock on

So in this case something along the lines of:

```
public class A
{
    private readonly object _syncLock = new object();
    public B B { get; private set; }

    public A()
    {
    }

    public void Add(B b)
    {
        lock (_syncLock)
        {
            // The actual logic
        }
    } 
}
```

This way the thread-safety is handled by the `Add` method itself so it isn't a concern of external calls.

Comment: I completely agree. However, I have a question. What if there are multiple fields to update in the class at one particular time. Would you expose the synclock object, make a method that takes several parameters or lock on every property? I don't think the latter would be an efficient solution as it would lock and unlock on every property change.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't expose the syncLock. The class should be in charge of managing its own state. Beyond that it depends on your use case. If the properties are always going to be updated together then it probably makes sense to add a method to handle updating them all simultaneously. But if you need to frequently update the properties individually the latter approach might be a better solution.